# MAUI: how to implement attached events?

Tags: c#, maui

What is a good way of implementing the equivalent of WPF's [attached events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/events/attached-events-overview?view=netdesktop-8.0) in MAUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I's possible to mimic WPF's attached events using Attached properties bound to `ICommand`s.

```
public class MyControlAttachedProperties : BindableObject
{
 public static ICommand GetMyCommand(MyControl d)
    {
        return (ICommand)d.GetValue(MyCommandProperty);
    }
    public static void SetMyCommand(MyControl d, ICommand value)
    {
        d.SetValue(MyCommandProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty MyCommandProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached(
        "MyCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(MyControlAttachedProperties), null);

}
```

```
<local:MyControl AttachedProperties:MyControlAttachedProperties.MyCommand="{Binding VmCommand}" />
```

Then, to fire the command, just retrieve it from the control's attached property and call its `Execute` method:

```
var command = MyControlAttachedProperties.GetMyCommand(myControl as myControl);
if (command != null)
{
    if (command.CanExecute())
    {
        command.Execute();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is a good way of implementing the equivalent of WPF's attached events in MAUI?

For MAUI, you can try to use `Behaviors`. This is similar to Attached events of WPF.

You can refer to the official doc: [.NET MAUI - Behaviors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/behaviors?view=net-maui-8.0#attached-behaviors) and also [sample for Behaviors](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/tree/main/8.0/Fundamentals/BehaviorsDemos).